# Convergence of a series $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} {2n\choose n} {\sum_{k=0}^n}{n\choose k} {n\choose {n-k}}({1\over3})^{2k}({1\over6})^{2n-2k}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, hypergeometric-function

I have trouble showing the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} {2n\choose n} {\sum_{k=0}^n}{n\choose k} {n\choose {n-k}}\bigg({1\over3}\bigg)^{2k}\bigg({1\over6}\bigg)^{2n-2k}$$ converges or not. I tried to write it in the form of hypergeometric series but made no progress. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Using convolution, one can verify that the inner sum is $(1+(1/3)^2)(1+(1/6)^2)$, so the series diverges.

Comment: Shouldn't the inner sum be a function of $n$? Maybe $(1+(1/3)^2)^n (1+(1/6)^2)^n$?

Comment: **Hint:** $~\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}^2x^k~=~(1-x)^n\cdot P_n\bigg(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\bigg),~$ where **P** is the famous [Legendre polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials).

Answer (score 0):

First note that

$$\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{2n}n\sum_k\binom{n}k\binom{n}{n-k}\left(\frac13\right)^{2k}\left(\frac16\right)^{2n-2k}\\\\
&\qquad=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{2n}n\sum_k\binom{n}{n-k}^2\left(\frac13\right)^{2k}\left(\frac13\cdot\frac12\right)^{2n-2k}\\\\
&\qquad=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{2n}n\sum_k\binom{n}{n-k}^2\left(\frac13\right)^{2n}\left(\frac12\right)^{2n-2k}\\\\
&\qquad=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{2n}n\left(\frac19\right)^n\sum_k\binom{n}{n-k}^2\left(\frac14\right)^{n-k}\\\\
&\qquad=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{2n}n\left(\frac19\right)^n\sum_k\binom{n}k^2\left(\frac14\right)^k\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now let

$$f(n)=\sum_k\binom{n}k^2\left(\frac14\right)^k\;,$$

and let $a_n$ be the sum of the squares of the coefficients of $(1+2x)^n$; clearly $f(n)=\dfrac{a_n}{4^n}$.

The sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is [OEIS A084771](http://oeis.org/A084771), and according to the FORMULA section of the entry it satisfies the asymptotic formula

$$a_n\sim\frac{3^{2n+1}}{2\sqrt{2\pi n}}\;.$$

From [Stirling’s approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) it’s easy to find that

$$\binom{2n}n\sim\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\;,$$

so

$$\binom{2n}n\left(\frac19\right)^nf(n)\sim\frac{4^n\cdot3^{2n+1}}{2^{3/2}\pi n\cdot9^n\cdot4^n}=\frac3{2^{3/2}\pi n}\;,$$

and the series diverges.